# Redis BGSAVE on Linux VM

Tags: linux, performance, redis

On high loads, I'm experiencing server hiccups on a RHEL Linux VM, when a
server does BGSAVE.

This is issue is not happening in a physical box.

What's the best solution for fixing this in a VM?

We are using RDB dumps and AOF is disabled.

$uname -a

Linux akm 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 #1 SMP Mon Feb 21 05:52:39 EST 2011
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Redis version: 2.2.12

Answer (score 1):

Are you experiencing high memory load?  When Redis does a BGSAVE, it forks the process.  This effectively doubles the amount of memory it's taking up.  If this causes your box to swap, it could bring everything to a screeching halt.

Solution:  Add more memory or try to reduce the size of your database.

Comment: It is generally wrong. The OS COW mechanism will allow pages to be shared between the two processes. In order to take twice the memory, the clients would have to update *all* the pages during the dump timeframe, which is unlikely.

Comment: @Didier - This is actually very possible if the Redis instance is part of a very busy queueing system.  I've seen it happen before.